# DevTool requests full access to YOURPATH, make sure that you do not expose any sensitive information dialog

Tags: chrome

I came across this warning message in chrome after I executed a command in the browser inspector, and realised this question had been asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310176/risk-of-adding-sensitive-files-to-chrome-devtools-workspace) but the answers do not contain so much information.

```
DevTool requests full access to YOURPATH, make sure that you do not expose any sensitive information
```

[image: tu]

What is the risk when I add a sensitive path to filesystem in Chrome DevTools? Chrome can read from it doesn't tell much about adversaries.

Comment: You are duplicating questions on StackExchange. If you want more focus on the other question, then interact with the question where it is. Don't cross-post it here.